Nexos condicionales with first person singular,con tal de que,como si,como y mientras
I listened to a grammar podcast by Hoy Hablamos  number 228. The podcast is free to listen to but the transcription is subscription based.
https://www.hoyhablamos.com/gram-228-nexos-condicionales-con-subjuntivo-2/
It deals with ''nexos condicionales'' like''mientras,como,como si and con tal de que''. It tells how a ''nexo condicional'' like ''como si'' takes the subjunctive,e.g.
''actuáis como si fueráis chicos pequenos''.
I understand this concept as explained in the podcast.
My question is based around if the subject is the same in both clauses,i.e.
''Actuo como si fuera chico pequeno''.(yo) Is this correct?
I have the same question for ''mientras'' and the other ''nexos'' above.
Example:
''puedo ir en monopatín mientras llevA casco''(yo)
or
''podía ir en monopatín mientras llevara casco''.(yo)/''podría haber ido en monopatín..''
i could have skateboarded if i were wearing a helmet.
OR
Como me hables así, te golperé.(if you talk to me like that,i will hit you)
Can ''como'' be used for first person singular statements in a threatening/warning manner? I mean to signify'' if ...''
I would appreciate if people could respond with first person singular examples for all of the ''nexos condicionales'' both in present subjunctive and imperfect subjunctive.
Con tal de que,mientras,como, and como si.
In the grammar books and sites that I searched there is a lack of examples of First Person Singular used in clauses.books like''Spanish Demystified'' and ''Kwiziq'' website.

En cuanto a tu primera pregunta, no necesariamente. Los conectores permiten introducir una nueva cláusula subordinada, pero cada cláusula tiene su propio sujeto, verbo y eventualmente su objeto. La estructura sería algo así como:
S1 + V1 (+ O1) + [conector] + S2 + V2 (+ O2)
O también puede invertirse a V1 + S1, o V2 + S2 dependiendo del caso, e incluso se podría comenzar la oración con la subordinada, es decir con V2 o S2.
Obviamente, dentro de cada cláusula debe concordar el sujeto con el verbo, entonces S1 concuerda con V1 y S2 concuerda con V2. Pero no necesariamente concuerda S1 con S2 o V1 con V2. Justo en tu ejemplo está bien que así sea, pero hay más posibilidades:

(yo) Hago como si (yo) fuera un chico pequeño.
(él) Hace como si (él) fuera un chico pequeño.
(yo) Hago como si (él) no existiera.
(él) Hace como si (yo) no existiera.

Como ves, todo depende de la situación.
En cuanto a tu segundo ejemplo, lo mismo aplica. En este caso, es la persona que va en el monopatín la que lleva el casco, así que lo correcto es:

(yo) Puedo ir en monopatín mientras (yo) lleve casco.
(yo) Podía ir en monopatín mientras (yo) llevara casco.

También vale:

(yo) Puedo ir en monopatín si llevo casco.
(yo) Podía ir en monopatín si llevaba casco.
Si llevo casco puedo ir en monopatín.
Si llevaba casco podía ir en monopatín.

Lo que me da pie para responder a tu segunda pregunta. No hay una regla exacta para la conjugación del verbo de la subordinada (V2); primero se elige la conjugación correcta para V1 y después todo va a depender de cuál sea el conector. En cuanto a los casos que trajiste:

mientras: generalmente va seguido del subjuntivo presente si es para hablar de una condición o una restricción.
con tal de que: va seguido de subjuntivo (presente o pasado).
como si: generalmente va seguido del subjuntivo.
como que: generalmente va seguido del indicativo.

Ejemplos para los que faltan:

Voy a hacer todo lo que sea necesario con tal de que (él) pueda ir a la fiesta.
Hice todo lo posible con tal de que (él) pueda ir a la fiesta. (la fiesta no pasó, mi trabajo terminó)
Hice todo lo posible con tal de que (él) pudiera a la fiesta. (probablemente la fiesta ya pasó)
Hago como si (él) no existiera.
Hago como que (él) no existe.

Los últimos dos casos refieren exactamente a lo mismo, el tiempo al que refieren ambas oraciones es el presente (está dado por V1) pero como ya dije la conjugación correcta del verbo subordinado está dada por el conector y puede que no tenga nada que ver con V1. En suma, yo creo que para aprender cuál es la conjugación correcta de V2 la única forma es buscar ejemplos con frases en libros o en internet donde aparezcan los conectores y después armar una lista de ejemplos con los conectores más comunes para memorizarlos, no veo otra alternativa.
Y en cuanto a tu última pregunta, está perfecto el uso de como.
‘como’ + [presente] + [futuro]

Como me hables así te golpeo.

es una construcción súper canónica para hacer amenazas. Sin embargo, por esa misma razón sólo va a aparecer en lo escrito: te pasarías de tragalibros si llegás a decir algo como eso. Si realmente estás pensando en amenazar a alguien, lo más común sería formularlo con ‘si’ + [presente] + [presente], y cambiar también el vocabulario. De modo que lo más común sería escuchar algo como:

Si me hablás así te cago a piñas.

O ‘te cago a trompadas’, ‘te reviento a hostias’, etc. etc. Cada país (y cada quién) va a tener su locución preferida para la última parte, pero esto ya es irse por las ramas—si todavía estás interesadx en amenazar personas, buscá ‘bromas telefónicas de Auronplay’, el vocabulario que se puede encontrar allí en todo a lo que refiere a agresiones físicas es muy rico, o sino podrías salir a caminar por alguna villa que sea bien jodida para tener una experiencia más realista pero eso no lo recomiendo para nada ;).

Very detailed and helpful answer. I must read it carefully to absorb it all and in case I have any further questions.@tac
